# How to write regex for website url with trailing pages

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write some regex that will match the following pattern, with the `http://www...`.

http://www.domain.com/ and then anything that follows it.  I need it match whether there is an "http://", a "www.", or any trailing pages.  Literally all I want the user entering is domain.com.  So I want to throw an error by matching http://www.domain.com/...

Here is what I have come up with:

`new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");`

But that only matches if there is an "http://" or "www.".  How do I catch the trailing pages in the URL? Any page.

Comment: So if they enter `domain.com/page` I want to catch that.

Comment: So you're basically saying you want to match either `http://` or `www.` ?

Comment: Or any pages.  Literally, all I want is domain.com to validate

Comment: Some sample inputs and outputs would really help, because I can't seem to understand your requirements.

Comment: The only that I want to pass validation is domain.com.  No pages following domain.com and no `http://` or `www.`  So i want the Regex to catch `domain.com/page` and `http://domain.com` and `www.domain.com`.  Does that help?

Comment: `domain.com` should not be caught by the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just turn it around and let the regular expression match domain.com, and than negate the outcome?

For example:

```
var foo = "domain.com";
if (! foo.match(/^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/)) {
  // throw error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about allowing the user to enter "whatever", and you pull out what you need?

```
function extractHost(userInput){
    var url = document.createElement('a');
    url.href = userInput;
    return url.hostname;
}

console.log(extractHost('http://stackoverflow.com/foo?bar=1'));

// stackoverflow.com
```

Or if you want to return 'false' for anything other than a hostname, change the `return` line to:

```
return url.hostname == userInput;
```

Comment: I like that.  Let me try it.

Comment: It's returning false for stackoverflow.com

Comment: I updated the code a couple minutes ago, make sure the you have the correct `return` line.  It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can match the rest of the url:

```
/(?:http[s]?:\/\/|www\.):?(?:[^\/]*)\/(.*)/.exec(str);
```

The result will be in the second element of the returned array.

```
/(:?http[s]?:\/\/|www\.):?(?:[^\/]*)\/(.*)/.exec('https://test.domain.com/page/page2');
```

returns

```
["https://test.domain.com/page/page2", "page/page2"]
```